# Identify duration on log file

Tags: text-processing, command

how to calculate duration of (Flushed time - Aggregated time) in the below log file using awk or perl scripts

```
09/03/2020 00:05:03.364 Aggregated 0 NMEs at a rate of 0 NMEs/sec
09/03/2020 00:05:03.366 Scheme S20_SessionClassAggregation tree contained 0 nmes, 0 flushed, 0 remain.
09/03/2020 00:05:03.582 Flushed 0 NMEs at a rate of 0 NMEs/sec
09/03/2020 00:20:03.598 Aggregated 0 NMEs at a rate of 0 NMEs/sec
09/03/2020 00:20:03.602 Scheme S20_SessionClassAggregation tree contained 0 nmes, 0 flushed, 0 remain.
09/03/2020 00:20:03.860 Flushed 0 NMEs at a rate of 0 NMEs/sec
```

example:

I need the difference from line 3 (009/03/2020 00:05:03.582) - line 1(09/03/2020 00:05:03.364) and line 6(09/03/2020 00:20:03.860) - line 4 (09/03/2020 00:20:03.598)

expected Results:

```
0 min 0 sec 218 ms
0 min 0 sec 262 ms
.
.
.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: With your example input do you want to get two duration values from line 3 - line 1 and line 6 - line 4? Please specify the expected output you want get from this input. Please also think about the case that the "Aggregated line might be a few milliseconds before midnight and the "Flushed" line after midnight. I suggest to extend the example to show such a case.

Comment: **Please [edit] your question** to add requested information or clarification. **Don't answer in comments.** Please also answer the question about the expected output matching the input. Your example might be too simple because it shows only a difference in the milliseconds value. Can you have carry to seconds, minutes, hours, day, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your timestamps always come in pairs, you can do it with `GNU sed` and `GNU coreutils`:

```
# Extract the relevant timestamps and convert them to secs + ns
<infile \
sed -nE 's/(.*) (Aggregated|Flushed).*/\1/; T; s/^/date -d "/; s/$/" +%s.%N/ep' |

# Find the time difference
sed '1~2 s/^/-/' |
paste -d+ - -    |
bc               |

# Print the difference in the desired format
while read dt; do
  date -u -d "1970/01/01 + $(printf "%.3f" $dt) sec" +'%_M min %S sec %3N ms'
done
```

Output:

```
 0 min 00 sec 218 ms
 0 min 00 sec 262 ms
```